# Are there any alternatives to using List.Single to get an element with a primary key?

Tags: .net, linq, collections

I have a List of User objects from my data store.

Now once it is already in memory the only way to get a user by his ID is to use the Single extension method. This is really performance degrading.

I know I could have used a dictionary instead of a list but this would be redundant. I would have to store the Primary Key 2 times. So is there another way to do what i want?

BTW I am making a custom class that can do something like this, but i was hoping for something out of the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could save your in-memory users in a [KeyedCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132438.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the primary key is a reference type, you'd only be storing a *reference* to the primary key twice.

Have you tried using `Dictionary<,>` and found it doesn't work well enough? It's certainly the most natural solution. `KeyedCollection<,>` (suggested by Mark) would certainly work too, but requires you to derive from the class - and I wouldn't like to guarantee it'll actually save any memory. (You'd need to know the implementation details - it could easily just use a Dictionary internally, for example.)

Comment: I think i'll try the KeyedCollection, it seems much cleaner.

Comment: @diamendev: If you say so. I'd personally say a single call of `list.ToDictionary(x => x.Id)` is pretty simple, but there we go... Admittedly `KeyedCollection` helps if you want to add things to it afterwards.